# Catching DOMException in javascript using try catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to catch the following error,

```
DOMException: NFC permission request denied
```

So I wrote a try catch and successfully caught an error which printed the above in console

```
  console.log(error); // prints above
  if (error === "DOMException: NFC permission request denied"){
    console.log("THIS IS WHAT I WANT");
  }
```

But the console log message never shows, is my if statement incorrect ?

Comment: Maybe try `error.message === ""` and also `JSON.stringify(error)` for more data

Comment: An error is not a string, so you can't really compare the two. You should get what you want this way: `error.toString() == "DOMException: ..."`

Comment: An [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error) has a message property which returns the actual message: `error.message`